# Any pointers to good AS3 code snippets/samples?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I am newbie in AS3 and learning day by day. I am looking for good AS3 code snippets/samples/small projects which I can use for learning purpose and for reference (with no dependency on Flash IDE because I use Flex SDK and Flash Develop). Also, I am specifically looking for tutorials/articles about Audio/Video streaming, creating own audio/video player, playing audio/video files and working with other media (such as images) and creating special effects. If there's any good websites(other than adobe.com) would be really really really thankful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you interesting in pure ActionScript projects or Flex projects too?

Comment: i would suggest http://gotoandlearn.com/

Comment: @Constantiner - As long as it can be developed using Free/Open Soure Tools (like Flash Develop and Flex SDK and don't have any dependency on Flash IDE or other paid tools) and can run on web (or cross platforms) I'm fine with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adobe.com stinks for most documentation ([Flex in a Week](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html) isn't bad). Here are a few flex/actionscript websites I use or have used:

http://actionscript.org/ Has a lot of ActionScript tutorials.

http://www.flexafterdark.com/ - some good tips and tricks.

http://active.tutsplus.com/ has some good information.

http://www.lynda.com (subscription based) has very good videos that can help you get started.

I would also highly recommend a few books. [Flex 3 Bible](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470287640)/[Flex 4 Bible](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470488956)[/ActionScript 3.0 Bible](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470135603)

Answer (score 2):

Google and [Flex in a Week](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to take a look at [Flex Examples blog](http://blog.flexexamples.com/). It contains really great and really simple samples to learn.

Comment: +1 For Flex Examples. I wish it weren't down so often though.

Comment: Although these flex examples are really good but I am looking for examples purely written in AS3. It would be really great if you can provide pointers of how to build video/audio player or streaming player. I want to learn how to deal with different types of media contents in Flash (using AS3 as I'm not using Flash Builder. I use Flash Develop and Flex SDK which are free and open source). Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I recommend you to look into OSMF framework http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/osmf/Open+Source+Media+Framework It is free, pure ActionScript and open source.

Answer (score 1):

Senocular is a great when it comes to explaining AS3. Check out his site below:

http://www.senocular.com

In particular his tutorial on AS3 is fantastic - it goes through everything new or challenging about AS3 like display lists and event listeners. It was the perfect primer for me when I stepped across to AS3.

http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withflashcs3/

Sencular is really popular on the http://www.kirupa.com forums (another good set of tutorials are there) plus I believe he works for Adobe now.

Otherwise checkout Grant Skinners work, recently he has been doing a lot JavaScript stuff, but do a search of actionscript and you will find a lot of stuff, especially around memory management.

http://gskinner.com/

Comment: I like the sites, but I am not sure these are great for a noobie.

Comment: I know what you mean but the senocular one is great, ranges from basic to advanced - for my 2c