# Flex - Some good source for practical examples

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Since I need to start working on flex within a week for my firm, I started learning flex.
I did watch some of the starting videos from Adobe ([here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/flex/videotraining/flex3/)).

But, I found those videos too slow for my learning process and they don't seem to provide with much practical application programs to try out with.

Though, I will continue with those videos over the week, can anyone suggest some good website/online resource that could provide me with some practical examples, that would easy to work out on Flex Builder. It would also ease my learning process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Flex 3 Essential Training](http://www.lynda.com/Flex-3-training/essential-training/438-2C.html). It will give you pretty good overview of Flex in a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

There was [a topic which possible contains useful links](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5667975/680503).

Answer (score 1):

Tour De Flex - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex.html Is a walkthrough of all the basic API's, simple examples that will get you up and started. It's an AIR app, just click the INSTALL button and it wil be installed on your machine.

Comment: At the moment, I don't require to learn AIR appln. I need some flash appln examples.

Comment: The application containing examples is an AIR app, not examples themselves. There are examples for both SWF and AIR in it.